# Managing Android layouts, there must be a better way

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to sort the layout for one of my Android apps, but I'm finding layouts a nightmare.

Principally I have to have a portrait and landscape layout for normal, small and large screens.  So thats 6 layouts to maintain to start with, let alone having to launch the app on three emulators each time because my UI widets don't load in the built in previewer.

I might be showing my ignorance as a fairly new developer, but there must be a better way!

Are there any tools out there to help with Android layouts?

Thanks

Comment: In general, if your layout is fairly simple you shouldn't need to create separate ones from small, medium and large screens. What are you doing that you found you needed to do so?

Comment: Sorry, Falmarri, but +1 from me

Comment: Although it seems to me that the author is missing (some) of the basics (I believe that Blindstuff answer nailed it), I think that this question is good enough considering the answers that we can (and did) get... it reveals more than it seems to, IMHO. I think that the Eclipse layout design is a bit cumbersome and could be improved, to make it easier/faster (for designers, mockups etc.). Anyway... that's what the tools mentioned here are for.

Answer (score 8):

You dont *need* to have that many layouts. Design only as many as you need, and never use absolute values, aditionally try to make everything look nice using fill_parent and wrap_content for you layout_width & layout_height tags. Android does most of the work it self.
This article contains a lot of usefull info:
[Supportng multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may find this applicaiton helpful for designing your layouts:

http://www.droiddraw.org/

Also, if you don't specify a layout for each rotation, android will use one - infact it can use one for everything. If you use fixed values it makes it much harder. Try using fill_parent and wrap_content, you android will take care of scaling the view for each screen type and rotation too.

As a tip, don't forget to include:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

above your relative or linear layout, and:

```
</ScrollView>
```

at the end - that way if the view doesn't fit on the screen (ie too much content) it will allow the user to scroll.

Comment: In my experience using droid draw, its a great tool to do some basic design work just to get a mock up or basic layout idea, but the best way to edit the layout is still old fashion text editing the XML. Since list views and dynamically generated content is a big thing in android these things dont show up unless you are runing the app and hence droidraw wont give you the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's built in layout "editor" shows a reasonably good example of what a layout looks like.  I would assume you're writing your application in Eclipse.  If not, I highly recommend it.  While not perfect, it's the best environment I've found.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to master the proper use of `RelativeLayout`'s and `LinearLayout`'s. Almost all of my Layouts will start with a Relative and have Linear nested inside. 
 I generally don't use LinearLayouts without having either height or width set to 0 and using the weight attribute to make everything the same size.